# how to manage user permissions components react?

Tags: reactjs, permissions

I would like to understand how to manage the permissions in my application in react of my components, the situation is the following, I have a component with a button inside that I don't want to appear if the user does not have a certain role, in this case I did a simple if in which through the store I take the role of the logged in user and check that it has a certain role in this case admin, if it is not an admin I do not see anything otherwise the button will appear:

```
{(state.userRole ==='admin')?(
                    <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.button}
                    startIcon={<AddIcon />}
                    onClick = {setModal}
                    >
                    Add
                    </Button>) : (<div>No permission</div>)
                }
```

This implementation, however, I do not like that much I find it not very elegant also because since I have different roles it can happen in some cases I could have a slew of concatenated if, for example it could happen that a button can see them both an admin and a normal user

```
(state.userRole ==='admin')|| (state.userRole ==='other_role_1')||(state.userRole ==='other_role_n)
```

such as could i handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to create an object and use it as a switch.
You would have to address each component that may or may not show for each role.

```
import React from 'react';

export function YourComponent({ role = 'guest' }) {
  // role is one of the three: 'admin', 'user', 'guest'
  const accessControlMap = {
    admin: {
      HeaderButton: () => <HeaderButton />, // admin and user both see the same component for HeaderButton
      BodyArea: () => <BodyArea />,
      AnotherThing: () => <Whatever />, // but different once for this component
    },
    user: {
      HeaderButton: () => <HeaderButton />,
      BodyArea: () => null,
      AnotherThing: () => <OtherThing />,
    },
    guest: {
      HeaderButton: () => null,
      BodyArea: () => null,
      AnotherThing: () => null,
    },
  };

  const { HeaderButton, BodyArea, AnotherThing } = accessControlMap[role];

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <HeaderButton />
      </header>

      <main>
        <BodyArea />
      </main>

      <AnotherThing />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, it seems like a good solution.

Comment: Feel free to mark it as the answer if it answers your question.